# Adding directory to PATH on Mac

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to add a directory to my path, and I'm having trouble. I have a `Macbook Pro` running `Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5`. To make the changes I used the command:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

It opened up the profile file and it looked like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/tools 
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/platform-tools 
#
# Your previous /Users/Banderson/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/Banderson/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-05-16_at_09:53:57
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-05-16_at_09:53:57: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for JRuby 1.7.0.RC1
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.jrubysave
PATH="${PATH}:/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin"
export PATH
```

Then I added this:

```
   export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/Documents/awstats-7.1/wwwroot/cgi-bin/
```

To make the `.bash_profile` look like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/tools 
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/platform-tools 
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Banderson/Documents/awstats-7.1/wwwroot/cgi-bin/
#
# Your previous /Users/Banderson/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/Banderson/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-05-16_at_09:53:57
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-05-16_at_09:53:57: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for JRuby 1.7.0.RC1
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.jrubysave
PATH="${PATH}:/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin"
export PATH
```

After I added that, I saved it, then in the terminal, I executed the `source ~/.bash_profile` command, quit the terminal window, started a new window, and tried to launch a file from the directory I added to the path, but it didn't work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

Here is what `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/bin:/Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8@global/bin:/Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/bin:/Users/Banderson/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/tools:/Users/Banderson/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/Banderson/Documents/awstats-7.1/wwwroot/cgi-bin/:/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin
```

Comment: why this `{}` around `PATH` ?

Comment: Likely unrelated, but you're including the existing `$PATH` at both the beginning and end of your new one with that third line.

Comment: so get rid of the $PATH at the end of the line that I added? I've done that and it doesn't seem to do anything. But thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: What editor did you use when modifying the file? It might not have used the correct type of line endings that the shell understands.

Comment: I used text edit. Do I need to use VIM or something?

Comment: @Matthias I updated the OP to show you what `echo $PATH` output is.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be moved to http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the inclusion of the rvm scripts. I guess, there your path is overwritten.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are the rvm scripts? Can I change them?

Comment: Actually, I just saw that your directory is in your path, thus I was wrong, the path is **not** overwritten. Did your check the execution rights?